# Is this histogram normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Im conducting a paired t test on SAS and wanted to check the assumption of normality. I know it's not massively important in a paired t test but unsure whether the results I have are skewed enough to effect the significance of the test?

[image: am]

Thanks

Comment: http://www.psychwiki.com/wiki/How_do_I_determine_whether_my_data_are_normal%3F

Comment: See im still unsure since there are an equal number of bars on the left and right hand side

Comment: Will you be able to make a statistical test for the data? Do you have the actual numbers that form the data?

Comment: I have the data yes, what sort of test?

Comment: Did you read the article that I linked? It speaks of several tests that you can make ...

Comment: I think i need to decide from the graph